# Scala- How to use Join operator with tuple'2 and tuple'3

Tags: scala

I have two lists of tuples

```
val firstT= List((S,1), (t,2), (H,2), (B,2), (D,1))
val secT=  List((1,S,1), (1,t,1), (1,H,1), (1,B,1), (2,t,1), (2,H,1), (2,D,1), (2,B,2))
```

I have to join the tuples to match between the

```
val res= secT.join(firstT).where { secT._2 } isEqualTo { firstT._1 }
```

It would be easier to use map, but in the Tuple'3, we can't use maps in this case.

How can I use join operator to join tuples ?

expected result: To join tuples this way to do operation later.

```
Join ( (1,S,1), (S,1) ) { return (1,S,1+1) }

Join ( (t,2),(1,t,1)) {  return (1,t,2+1)}

Join ( (H,2), (1,H,1)) { ...}
```

etc

I can handle the rest, but I want to understand how can join work ?

Comment: What result do you expect?

Comment: @user3378649 i still dont understand your question. Do you wish to merge two lists?

Comment: @Jatin: Check the answer below ! I should get similar results, but using join operator

Comment: The error I am getting everytime is : value join is not a member of List[(String, Int)]

Comment: That's because join is not a member of List[(String, Int)]! With the use of join and where, it seems to me you're expecting something database-y. Can you explain more about the context? Are you using some additional Scala library? Maybe http://squeryl.org/joins.html or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brute-force one:

```
scala> SecT.collect{
        case (a,x,c) if(firstT.filter(y => y._1 == x).headOption != None)  => 
                        (a,x,c+firstT.filter(y => y._1 == x).head._2)}
 res12: List[(Int, Symbol, Int)] = List((1,'S,2), (1,'t,3), (1,'H,3), (1,'B,3), (2,'t,3), (2,'H,3), (2,'D,2), (2,'B,4))
```

Comment: This is work ! But I am following a video course to learn scala. I need to use Join operator.

Answer (score 0):

To construct a Map from a Seq[Tuple3]:

```
val lookupMap= secT.map(x=>(x._2,x)).toMap
lookupMap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,(Int, String, Int)] = Map(t -> (2,t,1), B -> (2,B,2), H -> (2,H,1), D -> (2,D,1), S -> (1,S,1))
```

Which will probably solve your problem?